# Проблема c хранением большой строки в MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, какой тип надо установить столбцу в MSSQL, чтобы хранить строку размером ~ 5000 знаков? Сейчас я установил тип данных text, но текст обрезается. Я не считал, но остается где-то знаков 200 - 300. Я уже думал, что это почему-то режется во время исполнения кода, но даже если я руками забью туда где-то 1000 знаков, он всё равно режет. Что делать?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: Всё равно не работает, самое интересное, что он оставил столько же текста, сколько и при text, причем я сейчас поставил varchar(8000) и в блокноте отмерил 5000 символов , причем 5000 –ый символ выставил цифру(для определения вставил он 5000 или нет) , в рез – те он так эту цифру и не показал, т.е 5000 знаков он не вставил.